# Count Removed Lines

Tags: python

How can I remove duplicate lines from a string, and then print the amount of lines that were removed?

I got this:

```
import os


sentence = """Sentence1
Sentence1
Sentence2
Sentence3
Sentence4
Sentence4"""


spaces = sentence.replace(" ", "\n") #Makes one word per line
lines = os.linesep.join([s for s in spaces.splitlines() if s]) #Removes empty lines
duplicate = "\n".join(set(lines.split('\n'))) #Removes duplicate lines


numberlines = len(duplicate.split('\n')) #Counts lines



print(duplicate)
print'Lines:', numberlines
```

With this, the output is:

```
Sentence4
Sentence1
Sentence2
Sentence3
Lines: 4
```

How can I achieve this output:

```
Sentence4
Sentence1
Sentence2
Sentence3
Lines: 4
Removed Lines: 2
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Could you count the length difference `before - after`?

Comment: Working on that right now, might actually solve this myself. I'm new to python though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze your code line by line:

```
spaces = sentence.replace(" ", "\n") #Makes one word per line
```

So far, so good.

```
lines = os.linesep.join([s for s in spaces.splitlines() if s]) #Removes empty lines
```

OK, so you remove empty lines, but it is better to leave the result as a list, not glue it together into one string, because…:

```
duplicate = "\n".join(set(lines.split('\n'))) #Removes duplicate lines
```

…here you're splitting it again, and again joining the results into one string…

```
numberlines = len(duplicate.split('\n')) #Counts lines
```

…only to split it again. A better version:

```
spaces = sentence.split()                 # Makes one word per line
lines = [s for s in spaces if s]          # Removes empty lines
duplicate = set(lines)                    # Removes duplicate lines
numberlines = len(duplicate)              # Counts lines
removed_lines = len(lines) - numberlines
print '\n'.join(duplicate)
print 'Lines:', numberlines
print 'Removed:', removed_lines
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I will study this to make sure I understand everything, I'm really new to python and have barely taken any lessons, except maybe once or twice online. This code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set`:

```
Removed_lines = len(lines.split("\n")) - len(set(lines.split("\n")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os



sentence = """Sentence1
Sentence1
Sentence2
Sentence3
Sentence4
Sentence4"""



spaces = sentence.replace(" ", "\n") 
lines = os.linesep.join([s for s in spaces.splitlines() if s]) 
duplicate = "\n".join(set(lines.split('\n'))) 

numberlinesprev = len(sentence.split('\n'))
num1 = int(numberlinesprev)

numberlines = len(duplicate.split('\n'))
num2 = int(numberlines)

sum = num1 - num2



print(duplicate)
print'Lines Removed:', sum
print'Lines:', numberlines
```

Output:

```
Sentence4
Sentence1
Sentence2
Sentence3
Lines Removed: 2
Lines: 4
```